# Constructing a sequence/linked list through inheritance recursively in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Background: I'm reading the online book [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net) and one of the exercises in Chapter 6 mentions that a "Sequence" can behave similarly to a linked list. [Here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html#h_a0w19Kx5iq) is the link to the exercise, and I've copied a bit of relevant text:

> Another solution is to avoid changing state in the object. You can expose a method for getting the current element (without advancing any counter) and another for getting a new sequence that represents the remaining elements after the current one (or a special value if the end of the sequence is reached).

I am trying to build a Sequence by recursively calling the implementing class's (ArraySeq) constructor within the interface class. However when running a test in node, I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Sequence.ArraySeq`.

I've copied and pasted my (incomplete) implementation:

```
/**
 * Sequence interface
 */
function Sequence(current, rest) {
  this.current = current;
  this.rest = rest;
}

Object.defineProperty(Sequence.prototype, "end", {
  get: function() {
    return this.rest === undefined;
  }
});

Sequence.prototype.next = function() {
  return this.rest;
};

/**
 * Array implementation of sequence
 */
function ArraySeq(array) {
  if (array === []) {
    Sequence.call(undefined, undefined);
  } else {
    Sequence.call(array[0], new ArraySeq(array.slice(1)));
  }
}

ArraySeq.prototype = Object.create(Sequence.prototype);

/**
 * Logs all elements in a Sequence
 */
function logSequence(sequence) {
  while (sequence.rest !== undefined) {
    console.log(sequence.current);
    sequence = sequence.rest;
  }
}

logSequence(new ArraySeq([1, 2]));
```

Thank you for reading this far, any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `array.splice` is a function, and you are looking up its `1` property in `array.splice[1]`. Possibly want that as `array.splice(1)`?

Comment: Also, `array === []` will never be true; use `!array.length` to test for empty array.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Amadan. I have a feeling that my recursion isn't working though. When I do a `console.log(new ArraySeq([1, 2]);`, I'm getting an empty object back. I'm trying to figure out why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in comments:

- `array.splice[1]` will give you undefined. You want `array.slice(1)` - the whole array without the first element: `slice`, not `splice`. `array.splice(1)` will delete the second element from the array and return that element - not what you want.
- You wrote `Sequence` as a constructor, but you are not calling it as a constructor. Instead of `Sequence.call`, use `new Sequence`.
- Conversely, you are calling `new ArraySeq`, but `ArraySeq` does not look like a constructor. Use just `ArraySeq`, and make it return stuff (`return new Sequence...`).
- Use `if (!array.length)` to test for array being non-empty. `array === []`, and even `array == []`, can never return true, because objects (and thus arrays) are compared based on object identity, not equality, and you just created a new one (so there is no chance it is the same object as something that already existed).
- And of course, `ArraySequence` is not defined; that was supposed to be `ArraySeq`, right?

With those changes, your code works. EDIT: However, the exercise wants `ArraySeq` to be an object, so still a bit more work... First of all, "interface" is not an object. It is just how an object should behave. My go at the exercise would be:

```
function ArraySeq(array) {
  this.array = array;
  this.index = 0;
}

Object.defineProperty(ArraySeq.prototype, "end", {
  get: function() {
    return this.index >= this.array.length;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(ArraySeq.prototype, "next", {
  get: function() {
    return this.array[this.index++];
  }
});


/**
 * Logs all elements in a Sequence
 */
function logSequence(sequence) {
  while (!sequence.end) {
    console.log(sequence.next);
  }
}

logSequence(new ArraySeq([1, 2]));
```

The "interface" here is `.end` and `.next`. If you want to go the route of your quote, then it changes slightly. The interface here is `.end`, `.rest` and `.value`:

```
function ArraySeq(array) {
  this.array = array;
}

Object.defineProperty(ArraySeq.prototype, "end", {
  get: function() {
    return this.array.length == 0;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(ArraySeq.prototype, "rest", {
  get: function() {
    return new ArraySeq(this.array.slice(1));
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(ArraySeq.prototype, "value", {
  get: function() {
    return this.array[0];
  }
});


/**
 * Logs all elements in a Sequence
 */
function logSequence(sequence) {
  while (!sequence.end) {
    console.log(sequence.value);
    sequence = sequence.rest;
  }
}

logSequence(new ArraySeq([1, 2]));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @Amadan! The code does indeed function with your suggested fixes. Perhaps this is the wrong space to ask this, but can I ask why my `ArraySeq` "constructor" doesn't count as an Object? I can still call `new` on it, and its prototype is inherited from `Sequence`s prototype. Does the lack of properties not make it an Object?

Comment: "When I do a `console.log(new ArraySeq([1, 2]);`, I'm getting an empty object back.". In fact, now I belatedly see what you wanted to do - you wanted to initialise the `new ArraySeq` with `Sequence` constructor. The syntax for that would be `Sequence.call(this, array[0], new ArraySeq(array.slice(1)))`. Still, that is not really useful IMO - since you already built `ArraySeq`-specific functionality into `Sequence`, you might as well do it all in one object, like I did.

Comment: As I said, "make an interface" in JavaScript just means "decide which public methods/properties it will have", as JS is duck-typed and doesn't have formal interfaces like Java.

Comment: I just saw the most recent edit you made with your two solutions to the exercise. They helped quite a bit with my understanding of the relationship between "interfaces", inheritance and objects in JavaScript. I come from a predominately Java, C#, and C++ background which is why my instinct went towards a "generic" Sequence object interface to inherit from. Thanks again for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, if you come from those, you should realise what an interface is - a way for everyone to agree how to use an object. This way, you can make `RangeSeq`, define `end` and `next`, and then use it in exactly the same way - `logSequence` doesn't need to know if an object is a `RangeSeq` or an `ArraySeq`, as long as it has `end` and `next` it's all good. But since they share no common *functionality*, they do not need to inherit anything (unless you want a trivial parent that will let you test for `arraySeq instanceof Sequence`).

Answer (score 0):

first, `splice` is method.

`array.splice(1)` instead of `array.splice[1]`.

and use array.length == 0 in array === [].

if two object is different object, then === operator treated as false even all element is same.